# Download Salesforce Marketing Cloud Journey Builder History via REST API Returned all ContactKey as Contact Unknown

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

[I tried this method from SFMC Summer 23 update](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_2023_summer_jb_download_jb_history_via_rest_api.htm&type=5) by [REST posting to interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/download](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/downloadJourneyHistory.html) and get a CSV response back.

Every other columns worked great but all ContactKey value are having values as Contact Unknown, I have tried multiple combination of journey filters and they all returned Contact Unknown.

Posting to /interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/search gives normal contactKey value.

Would you mind sharing what could be the potential issues? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Theres a known issue regading this topic: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000tIwpHAAS/contactkey-returns-as-contact-unknown-in-journey-history-download-api.

Just add the 'id' field as a column for downloading and its solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with "contactKey": "Contact Unknown" [with this fellow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76270007/salesforce-marketing-cloud-journey-history-api)

I think when we use the API /interaction/v1/interactions/journeyHistory for the first time, something is not ready.

After a few hours, I did exactly that again and ContactKey starts populating